# Seg fault when trying access elements in a 3d vector

Tags: c++, c++11, multidimensional-array, segmentation-fault, stdvector

So my goal here to be able to access each element in a `5x5x5` *3D Vector*. When I call the `toString` function I get a *segfault error*. This is the first time I have initialized a *3d vector*. But from all the googling I did I found this initialization to be recommended but that is where I believe the problem is.

Do forgive me if the answer is super simple, I May have just gone blind to the simple things.

```
vector<vector<vector<int> > > maze(5,vector<vector<int> >(5,vector<int>(5)));

string Pathfinder::toString() const
{
  string mazeStr = "";
  cout << maze.size()<< endl;
  for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++){
      for(int k = 0; k < 5; k++){
        cout << k << endl;
        mazeStr = mazeStr + to_string(maze[i][j][k]) + " ";// seg fault problem
        cout << mazeStr <<".mazeStr"<< endl;
      }
      mazeStr = mazeStr + "/n";
    }
    mazeStr = mazeStr + "/n";
  }
  return mazeStr;
}
```

Comment: If the size is known at compile-time when you build the program, why not use e.g. `std::array` instead? Would make the initialization a little simpler at least.

Comment: Please provide [mre]. As this code is not it, the problem can be caused by undefined behavior anywhere in the code.

Comment: `string Pathfinder::toString()` --  We need to know if this instance of `Pathfinder` is valid.  If I took that code and put it all in `main`, I highly doubt there would be an error.

Comment: Not seeing anything. Suggestion: temporarily replace `maze[i][j][k]` with `maze.at(i).at(j).at(k)` to see if you can get a more helpful exception.

Comment: @user4581301 I did so and got this libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type std::out_of_range: vector

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of hard-coding 5 in the loops, use the `vector` sizes. Even better, use [range-based `for`.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for)

Comment: @user4581301 so I changed the 5 in each loop the vector sizes but the loops never are entered. The sizes of the vectors is 0 after I defined them to be 5? Is there something wrong with my initialization?

Comment: An exception means the indexes are not as advertised. Somewhere  `maze` got changed and one or more `vector`s are not size five. Now you have to find out where the change took place.

Comment: @user4581301 gotcha, okay thank you!

Comment: @ThomasS. -- I will use my crystal ball and predict that you initialized a local `maze` vector, and not the one you think you initialized.  In other words, something looking like this rookie mistake: `Pathfinder::Pathfinder() { vector<vector<vector<int> > > maze(5,vector<vector<int> >(5,vector<int>(5))); }`

Comment: This is a great time to make that [mcve] @AlgirdasPreidžius was talking about. More often than not as you cut the program down to get to the minimum code needed to produce the error, you get in a few cuts before the reduced amount of code makes the bug obvious and you fix it yourself. Because if this, it's usually a waste of your time to write a question before creating a [mcve].

Comment: Another great tool is the debugger. There is nothing like using the debugger to look in on the variables while stepping through the code to see where things went wrong. Often seeing what happened instead of what you wanted is all you need to figure out what you should have done instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given code, I do not see any out of bound. However, you could use [range-based-for-loop](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) instead of index-based one, bywhich you can make sure it will not be from the above function.

```
std::string toString() const
{
    std::string mazeStr = "";
    for (const std::vector<std::vector<int>>& vector2D: maze)
    {
        for (const std::vector<int>& vec: vector2D)
        {
            for (const int element: vec)  mazeStr += std::to_string(element) + " ";
            mazeStr += "/n";
        }
        mazeStr += "/n";
    }
    return mazeStr;
}
```